# Example of a proper dense retract?

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Proposition: Let $X$ be a topological space, let $A \subset X$ be a dense subset.

Under the further conditions

1. $A$ is "sequentially dense" in $X$, meaning the "sequential closure" of $A$ in $X$ (consisting of all points in $X$ which are topologically limits of sequences in $A$) is all of $X$;
2. and, topological limits of sequences in $X$ are unique (when they exist) (e.g., if $X$ is Hausdorff);

then $A$ cannot be a retract of $X$ unless $A = X$.

Proof: If $r : X \rightarrow A$ is a retract,
pick any $x \in X$;
using 1 pick a sequence $A \ni a_i \rightarrow x$;
then by continuity $r(a_i) \rightarrow r(x) \in A$;
but since $r$ is id on $A$ we have $r(a_i) = a_i$;
so now, applying 2 we have $x = r(x) \in A$.
Having shown $X \subseteq A$, we conclude $A = X$.

---

My question is, would anyone know of counter-examples showing the Proposition fails when either condition 1 or 2 is dropped? (Or, is there a stronger proof which allows 1 or 2 to be dropped or relaxed?)

Comment: Just replace sequences with nets everywhere and the proof works with just "dense" instead of "sequentially dense" for any Hausdorff space.  More generally, the same argument shows any retract of a Hausdorff space is a closed subset.

Comment: @EricWofsey I see, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y$ be any nonempty set and $p$ a point not in $Y$. Topologise $X=Y\cup\{p\}$ so that a nonempty subset $U\subset X$ is open iff $p\in U$. Then $\{p\}$ is a dense, sequentially dense retract of $X$. Of course $X$ does not have unique limits.

As pointed out in the comments, any retract of a Hausdorff space is closed. Thus there is no Hausdorff space with a proper dense subspace which is a retract.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example!